# How can I determine the source of the subreport when the *.rdl file is secretive?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, subreport, reportbuilder, rdl

I am generating a spreadsheet using the same data source that a report created in SQL Server Report Builder uses. I downloaded the report's *.rdl file, and am using the three datasets it generates, two from simple queries, and one from a complex Stored Procedure.

Both the *.rdl file and the project in MS SQL Server Report Builder show me that there are only these two queries and the Stored Proc plainly affiliated with this report.

I am successfully getting all this data - the two queries supply values that I use to populate comboboxes, and the Stored Proc returns several fields which I use in the report's "Summary" section.

However, the legacy report, which I can generate either from SSRS (web page) or directly from Report Builder ALSO print a "Detail" section below the "Summary" section.

I don't know where this data is coming from - the *.rdl file contains only this reference to a "subreport" as a clue:

```
   <Subreport Name="subreport1">
        <Parameters>
          <Parameter Name="BegDate">
            <Value>=Parameters!BegDate.Value</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter Name="EndDate">
            <Value>=Parameters!EndDate.Value</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter Name="Member">
            <Value>=Parameters!Member.Value</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter Name="Unit">
            <Value>=Parameters!Unit.Value</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter Name="Type">
            <Value>=Fields!T.Value</Value>
          </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
        . . .
```

I don't supply a "Type" parameter - I get the "Summary" data using the other four parameters. And the values displayed in the subreport do not appear in the *.rdl file. Where could these be coming from?

I look for the returned values from the Stored Proc this way:

```
string[] columnNames = dtPriceComplianceResults.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
    .ToArray();
if (columnNames.Length > 5)
{
    MessageBox.Show("more than 5");
    // TODO: If there are more fields, use these to generate the "Details" section of the report
}
```

...but it never has more than the few fields which are used to populate the "Summary" section of the report/spreadsheet.

Is it possible that if I supply a value to the "Type" parameter, I might get more data? Even if so, it's highly vexing/perplexing to me that there seems to be no reference to this subreport's data source within the *.rdl file.

### UPDATE

Is it possible that the "Type" parameter is supplied for the user right in the *.rdl file? (I'm home now, and don't have access to it to look, but I wonder if that's a common pattern for *.rdl files, or at least something that's possible).

If so, maybe the Type parameter provides returns those additional fields.

Comment: The `<Subreport>` should have a child element called: `<ReportName>` that contains a path to the subreport (within the SSRS pseudo-folders).  Something like: `<ReportName>/Dev/TestSubReport</ReportName>`  Do you see that element in the `RDL` you downloaded?

Comment: Thanks; I'll check it tomorrow, when I'm back at the grindstone.

Comment: As David says, the detail subreport is actually another report linked into this report and all the datasets it uses are in that report, not the main one. The `Type` parameter is a parameter of the subreport, not the main report, and gets supplied the value from the current report's `T` field when the subreport is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Subreport>` element in `rdl` has a required child element of `<ReportName>`.

If you look at the value of that element it should have a path to the subreport (in terms of the pseudo-folders on the SSRS server).  You should be able to go to that path on the SSRS server and download the `RDL` file for the subreport the same way you did for the primary report.

I created a few test reports and subreports to check this.  Then I did some digging to find docs online -- it is not *so* secretive but it was not so easy-to-find either.

The schema for the `RDL` file XML clearly shows that `<ReportName>` is a required element for `<Subreport>`.

[RDL File XML schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd)

Comment: Thanks; this has saved me much gnashing of teeth and scratching of follicles.